# How do you deploy google app engine with travis-ci, and run tests with py.test?

Tags: google-app-engine, travis-ci, pytest

I have an app that is tested in travis-ci using py.test. The idea is that it will get pushed to travis-ci which downloads and installs the required modules in a `lib` folder for `GAE` to run properly. This is what my travis file looks like:

language: python
    sudo: false
    python:
    - '2.7'

```
cache:
- pip

addons:
  apt:
    packages: 
      - python-protobuf

before_install:
- openssl <credential stuff>
- pip install --upgrade pip
- mkdir -p lib

install:
  - pip install -r requirements.txt -t lib/

script:
- PYTHONPATH="$(pwd):$(pwd)/lib:${PYTHONPATH}"
- export PYTHONPATH
- echo ${PYTHONPATH}
- pytest tests/

deploy:
  provider: gae
  ...
  <deploy stuff>
```

The problem is, when I run py.test it ignores the modules that were installed in the `lib` folder. When I run the following in the test script:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/home/travis/build/AndersenLab/CeNDR/lib/")
```

They still are not recognized. Further - if I run this:

```
import pip
print(pip.get_installed_distributions())
```

The modules in the lib folder are not being recognized. They can't be imported. Here is an example of the travis-ci results: https://travis-ci.org/AndersenLab/CeNDR/builds/176450179